# Using the Terrain Height in Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For a script i need the Terrain Height (found under `Resolution` in `Terrain`).

I tried it with `terrainData.heightmapHeight` and `terrainData.heightmapResolution` but both of them seem to be wrong.

I made a screenshot so that you can easily see what value i need:

[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`terrainData.size`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData-size.html) to get the maximum size of the terrain in world units, so for that value, it would be `terrainData.size.y`